# Paypal - customize return url with dynamic params

Tags: javascript, authentication, paypal

I set up a button to connect with Paypal on my website.

BUT

I would like to pass some parameters in the return url, it seems that it is not possible. I have read the documentation 10 times and got no more informations.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/

For example = https://returnurl?id=12345.

Does anyone know if this is possible and who has done it before ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

If you set a Redirect URL in the app without the parameters and it works, does adding the parameters on to that working base URL (only to the redirect_uri in your code) not work?

If not, then assuming they are being redirected back to a page on the same server they started at, the other best/simplest solution is probably to use a webserver session to story any additional info of this type so it's available on return pageload.

If it's pure client-side JavaScript then browser local storage could work, though it's strange to have to resort to that and Log in with PayPal requires server calls to do anything useful with an authorization_code anyway.

Comment: No, this does not work unfortunately. The return url in the code must be exactly the same as on the developer dashboard. 

The domain of my return url is not the same as initial request, so i cannot use local storage. it's crazy that paypal does not provide anything for this use case

Comment: Return to the same domain first. If you need to go elsewhere, do it next including whatever value